# Iterating through a list being modified by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multithreaded programming, and have a question. How do I get each thread to iterate through all the elements in a list being added to by a different thread?

Here's a simple program to demonstrate.  I have a single list of integers, and 10 threads, numbered 1 through 10, that are working on it.  Each thread is to write all the values in the list to a StringBuilder.  After a thread writes all the values in the list, it adds its number to the list, then terminates.

I'm trying to get each thread to keep checking the list for elements until the list is no longer being modified by any other thread, but am having trouble with the locking on it.  If successful, the program would have output that might look like:

```
3: 1,
8: 1,3,2,4,5,7,
6: 1,3,2,4,5,7,8,
9: 1,3,2,4,5,7,8,6,
7: 1,3,2,4,5,
10: 1,3,2,4,5,7,8,6,9,
5: 1,3,2,4,
4: 1,3,2,
2: 1,3,
1:
```

Which happens sometimes, but often two or more of the threads finish before the lock is set, so the iteration ends prematurely:

```
1: 
2: 1,5,4,8,7,3,10,
10: 1,5,4,8,7,3,
9: 1,5,4,8,7,3,10,2,
3: 1,5,4,8,7,
7: 1,5,4,8,
5: 1,    <<one of these threads didn't wait to stop iterating. 
4: 1,    <<
8: 1,5,4,
6: 1,5,4,8,7,3,10,2,
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

===========

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ListChecker implements Runnable{

static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

int id;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); 

public ListChecker(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i=0;

    do{
        while (i < list.size()){            
            result.append(list.get(i++)).append(',');
        }   
        if (!lock.isLocked()){
            break;
        }
    }while (true);                  
    addElement(id);
    System.out.println(id + ": " + result.toString());
}

public void addElement(int element){
    try{
        lock.lock();
        list.add(element);  
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        ListChecker checker = new ListChecker(i);
        new Thread(checker).start();
    }   
}   
}
```

---

Edit:  Thanks for the help so far.  I should clarify, that I would like for each thread to be iterating through the list at the same time.  In my case, there's a lot of processing that needs to be performed on each element of the list by each thread (instead of appending to a StringBuffer, I'm doing a lot of comparisons of a candidate item to a list of finalists).  So, having each thread be able to work on the same list at the same time is required for the multithreading to improve my performance.  So, I don't think locking around the entire iteration, or putting the whole iteration is a synchronized(list) block, will work.

---

Edit 2: I think I got it.  The trick was not just to synchronize on the list when adding elements to it, but also when determining if there are any more elements.  This prevents thread 2 from stopping its iteration before thread 1 finishes adding to the list.  It looks a bit kludgy, but this keeps the code that I need to run in multiple threads outside the synchronize block, so my real case should get the performance increase I need.

Thanks to everyone who helped!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListChecker2 implements Runnable{

    static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int id;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); 

    public ListChecker2(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        do{
            synchronized (list) {           
                if (i >= list.size()){
                    list.add(id);
                    System.out.println(id + ": " + result.toString());
                    return;
                }
            }
            result.append(list.get(i++)).append(',');
            System.out.println("running " + id);

        }while(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=1; i<=30; i++){
            ListChecker2 checker = new ListChecker2(i);
            new Thread(checker).start();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: The danger is that one thread will get to the end of the list (1) and add a new entry (2) while another thread adds its entry between (1) and (2). You will then have a thread that has not looked at all of the entries. Would you consider using a specially crafted list that automatically locks itself to your thread as soon as it iterates to the last entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much more simply by synchronizing on the list.

```
public class ListChecker implements Runnable {
  // Number of threads.
  static final int THREADS = 10;
  // The list.
  static final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(THREADS);

  // My ID
  int id;

  public ListChecker(int id) {
    // Remember my ID.
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // My string.
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();
    // Wait for exclusive access to the list.
    synchronized (list) {
      // Build my string.
      for ( Integer i : list ) {
        result.append(i).append(",");
      }
      // Add me to the list.
      list.add(id);
    }
    System.out.println(id + ": " + result.toString());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= THREADS; i++) {
      ListChecker checker = new ListChecker(i);
      new Thread(checker).start();
    }
  }
}
```

This is my output. A bit boring I'm afraid but it proves it works.

```
1: 
2: 1,
3: 1,2,
4: 1,2,3,
5: 1,2,3,4,
6: 1,2,3,4,5,
7: 1,2,3,4,5,6,
8: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
9: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
10: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
```

**Added**

If you need to avoid locking the whole list (as your edit suggests) you could try a special list that locks itself whenever it delivers the last entry. You then need to specifically unlock it of course.

Sadly, this technique does not handle the empty list situation very well. Perhaps you can think of an apt solution to that.

```
public class ListChecker implements Runnable {
  // Number of threads.
  static final int THREADS = 20;
  // The list.
  static final EndLockedList<Integer> list = new EndLockedList<Integer>();
  // My ID
  int id;

  public ListChecker(int id) {
    // Remember my ID.
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // My string.
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    // Build my string.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      result.append(i).append(",");
    }
    // Add me to the list.
    list.add(id);
    // Unlock the end lock.
    list.unlock();
    System.out.println(id + ": " + result.toString());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
      ListChecker checker = new ListChecker(i + 1);
      new Thread(checker).start();
    }
  }

  private static class EndLockedList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    // My lock.
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    // Were we locked?
    private volatile boolean locked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean add(T it) {
      lock.lock();
      try {
        return super.add(it);
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    }

    // Special get that locks the list when the last entry is got.
    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
      // Get it.
      T it = super.get(i);
      // If we are at the end.
      if (i == size() - 1) {
        // Speculative lock.
        lock.lock();
        // Still at the end?
        if (i < size() - 1) {
          // Release the lock!
          lock.unlock();
        } else {
          // Remember we were locked.
          locked = true;
          // It is now locked for putting until specifically unlocked.
        }
      }
      // That's the one.
      return it;
    }

    // Unlock.
    void unlock() {
      if (locked) {
        locked = false;
        lock.unlock();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output (notice the mishandling of an empty list):

```
2: 
8: 
5: 
1: 
4: 
7: 
6: 
9: 
3: 
10: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
11: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
12: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
13: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
14: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
15: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
16: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
17: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
18: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
19: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
20: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,
```

Comment: Thanks, O.C.  Please see my edit; I think this limits the iteration to a single thread, which I would like to prevent.

Comment: Points to you, since your comments finally made this stuff make sense, and the idea of the EndLockedList was pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen a tough case to get your feet wet. Reading and writing objects at the same time is complex, never recommended and often specifically prevented (ie won't work in with an Iterator and a List)

BUT

If you must do this, you should synchronize on your list before you add an element, and after you add the element, call list.notifyAll, which will wake up threads that are waiting for more results. Meanwhile, your other threads should read to the end, then synchronize on the list(you need to synchronize on the object to call wait, notify, or notifyAll) and call wait on it.

BTW A much easier way to do this is to use the listener / observer/observable pattern, though listener patternss operate (typically) single threaded. You might want to google for tutorials on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a method like Collections.synchronizedList(List list)

this is how you use it:

```
   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
   ...
   synchronized (list) {
   Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
   while (i.hasNext())
       foo(i.next());
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom!  Please see my edit; I'd like the iteration to occur in multiple threads at the same time if possible, but I think this change limits it to a single thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your run method.  and let me know if it is working as per ur expectation or not  ?

```
public void run() {
int i=0;
    lock.lock();
    while (i < list.size()){            
      result.append(list.get(i++)).append(',');
}   
addElement(id);
lock.unlock();``
System.out.println(id + ": " + result.toString());
}
```

Comment: This does give the correct results, but if I understand it correctly, it does so by limiting iteration to a single thread at a time.  You can see this if you print each thread's id within the while loop, especially if you increase the number of threads from 10 to 30 or so.  I think that Tom's solution of putting the Iterator in a synchronized(list) block does the same thing.  Ideally multiple threads could be iterating the same list at the same time, but then pause whenever the list is updated.  But thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, since list is shared we should synchronize access else result will not be correct